# Collection .Contains() not working

Tags: vb.net

I've check everywhere and can't find a solution. I have the following

```
Dim users as New List(of TUser)

Private Sub AddSelectedUsers()

For Each user as TUser in gridSelectedItems()

If Not users.Contains(user) Then

users.Add(user)

End If

Next

End Sub
```

The "Contains" is not working. I keep getting duplicates on the users list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The List.Contains() method uses the default equality operator. Since TUser appears to be a class, List.Contains() will only match if you are referencing the exact same instance of TUser in both comparisons, apparently isn't the case. See a more detailed explanation [here](http://codebetter.com/blogs/david.hayden/archive/2005/02/22/51364.aspx).

The solution is to implement an equality override for the TUser class, as per the example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336aedhh%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Comment: I suspected that might've been the problem because gridSelectedItems() is a list passed "ByRef" to this form. I'll give this a shot.

Comment: I ended up overriding the Equals in my TUser class and that works.